# Open ssh remote file within emacs with interactive terminal issues

Tags: ssh, emacs, tramp

I try to open a remote ssh file within emacs whose server runs an old ksh version which have gave me some headaches in the past. Additionaly, its `.profile` file is interactive so it requires some user interaction, but that can be solved later. So far I have the usual:

> tramp file pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

To do bash scripting I solve this problem by applying the `-tt` flag to `ssh`, to force interactive session, although I don't know if in this case that's what I need.

How could I personalize the flags used by `C-x C-f`' ssh connection, or solve that error message in particular?

Answer (score 2):

Add an entry with proper flags in `~/.ssh/config`, and use the nickname of that entry as host in your Tramp file name.